# Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys

Tags: arrays, angularjs, json, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

is there anyone can help me what should i do with this err , i dont know what happend with this issue , i just want to display json array from database server to html using angular syntax (ng-repeat) but i got an error say that *Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: datateman in datatemans, Duplicate key: string:", Duplicate value: "*

here is the code ..

```
     <div class="bar bar-header">
    <button class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
    <div class="h1 title">Data Teman</div>
    <button class="button button-clear button-positive">LogOut</button>
  </div>

<ion-view>
    <ion-content padding="false" class="has-header">
        <ion-refresher
            pulling-text="Pull to refresh..."
            on-refresh="showData()">
          </ion-refresher>
        <ion-list show-Delete = "data.showDelete" show-Reorder = "data.showReorder">
            <ion-item class="item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-repeat="datateman in datatemans" type="item-text-wrap" href="#/tab/teman/{{datateman.id}}">
                <img ng-src="{{datateman.icon}}">
                <i class="icon ion-ios7-arrow-right"></i>
                <h2>{{datateman.username}}
                    <br> 
                    <font size="2" color="gray" >Spesialis : {{datateman.password}}</font>
                </h2>
                <ion-delete-button class="ion-minus-circled" ng-click="delete(datateman);"></ion-delete-button>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

and here is the code where i get the json array ..

```
.factory('temanService', function($http) {
    var baseUrl = 'http://dwellingtime.net23.net/DwellingTime/';
    return {
        getAll: function() {
            return $http.get(baseUrl+'select.php');
        },
        getId: function (temanId){
            return $http.get(baseUrl+'select_id.php?id='+temanId); 
        },
        create: function (datateman){
            return $http.post(baseUrl+'insert.php',datateman,{
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8;'
                }
            });
        },
        update: function (datateman){
            return $http.post(baseUrl+'update.php',datateman,{
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8;'
                }
            });
        },
        delete: function  (id){
            return $http.get(baseUrl+'delete.php?id='+id);
        }
    };

});
```

Comment: Probably your data may contain duplicate values. To resolve this just change your ng-repeat="datateman in datatemans" to ng-repeat="datateman in datatemans track by $index"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The acutal problem is  described [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes)

AngularJS does not allow duplicates in a `ng-repeat` directive. This means if you are trying to do the following, you will get an error.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in [a,a,a]">
```

However, changing the above code slightly to define an index to determine uniqueness,

```
<div ng-repeat="item in [a,a,a] track by $index">
```

Replace your `ng-repeat="datateman in datatemans"` by `ng-repeat="datateman in datatemans track by $index"`

**html**

```
<div class="bar bar-header">
    <button class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
    <div class="h1 title">Data Teman</div>
    <button class="button button-clear button-positive">LogOut</button>
</div>
<ion-view>
    <ion-content padding="false" class="has-header">
        <ion-refresher pulling-text="Pull to refresh..." on-refresh="showData()">
        </ion-refresher>
        <ion-list show-Delete="data.showDelete" show-Reorder="data.showReorder">
            <ion-item class="item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-repeat="datateman in datatemans track by $index" type="item-text-wrap" href="#/tab/teman/{{datateman.id}}">
                <img ng-src="{{datateman.icon}}">
                <i class="icon ion-ios7-arrow-right"></i>
                <h2>{{datateman.username}}
                   <br> 
                     <font size="2" color="gray" >Spesialis : {datateman.password}}</font>
                </h2>
                <ion-delete-button class="ion-minus-circled" ng-click="delete(datateman);"></ion-delete-button>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: thanks before ,it's work but the result is too many data that are not like what i have in my database server,can you explain what is the meaning of "track by $index" that you mean in this case ? ,thanks